# Extjs 6.0 Modern: Treelist without store?

Tags: javascript, extjs, tree

So, I'm new to Extjs, and as part of my learning I'm trying to create a simple FAQ-Style tree list.

All the examples I've seen involve creating the UI widget (Please forgive the loose terminology) in the view file, and in a separate ViewModel file actually populating the list with its data. It looks something like

```
Ext.define('Namespace.view.tree.TreeList',
...
...
items:[{
    xtype: 'treelist',
    reference: 'treelist',
    bind: '{navItems}'
}]
```

with the parents and children of the tree laid out in a store called navItems.

Is there a way I can merge the two files into one? Can I define the trees data inside the same items as the tree? Or failing that, can I define the store in the same .js?

I apologize if these are stupid questions - I'm more far familiar with CPP than Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can define it directly in the view. The [store config](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/Ext.list.Tree.html#cfg-store) in the treelist accepts also object. So you can define the store directly in it.

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    fullscreen: true,
    title: 'Tree',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'treelist',
        store: {
            root: {
                // data defined in here
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

You can see it in action here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1h0b